# The code I've written doesn't change from the color red after having my button clicked. What have I done wrong in this case?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class TrafficLight{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Light");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        TrafficLightP panel = new TrafficLightP();

        frame.getContentPane().add(new TrafficLightP());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}    




import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrafficLightP extends JPanel {
    private int count;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;

    public TrafficLightP(){
        /*
        Traffic light color coded as
        1. Red
        2. Yellow
        3. Green
        */

        button = new JButton ("Button!");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        label = new JLabel("Traffic Light Button");

        add(button);
        add(label);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event){
            //Possible area where it messed up..?
            count++;
            count = count%3;
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        TrafficLightP.super.paintComponent (g);
        if (count == 0){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval (20, 30, 50, 50);
        }
        else if (count == 1){
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval (20, 30, 50, 50);
        }
        else if (count == 2){
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval (20, 30, 50, 50);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.white);
    }
}
```

Prompt: Design and implement an application that draws a traffic light and uses a push button to change the state of the light. Derive the drawing surface from the JPanel class and use another panel to organize the drawing surface and the button.

What have I done wrong in this case where the button doesn't change the color from red --> yellow --> green? If so, can someone give me advice for the future to fix problems like these? I haven't worked with JPanel much...

Comment: maybe initialize count to an initial state like  0 or 1 or 2. and call paintComponent :P

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo... I'm guessing the problem was because I wasn't able to put another shape on top of another?

Comment: @vk3105: you would never directly "call paintComponent". It's called by the JVM as a call-back method. You can *suggest* that it be called by calling `repaint()` however.